# VSCode上のJupyter Notebookで、sklearn配下のメンバーを呼び出そうとすると静的解析ではエラーが出るけど実行できる

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, scikit-learn, ipython

## 状況

Pythonを使ったデータ分析関連。Pandas-Profilingを使おうとしてます。
Pandas-Profilingに渡すデータを作るのにsklearnを使おうとしたんですが、そこでpylanceがエラーを吐く。でも、実行できます。

**と、思ったら、実際にPandas-Profilingにデータを渡して実行するとipython側でエラーが出ます。

先ほどColabでも試してみたところこちらは普通に実行できました。謎です。**
5/22追記　太字になっている内容は解決済みです

[image: colabでの実行画面]

## 原始コード実況中継

モジュールがちゃんと導入できてないって線はない…はず。

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

---

```
CH = fetch_california_housing()
df = pd.DataFrame(CH.data, columns= CH.feature_names)
df['MedHouseVal'] = CH.target
df.head(3)
```

ここで実行。pylanceはCH配下にdata、feature_names、targetなんてねえよ！って怒ってます。

```py
profile_df = ProfileReport(df, explorative=True)
profile_df.to_file("profile_df.html")
profile_df
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

エラー。ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipywidgets'
ちょっとよくわかりません。

## 環境

VSCodeにJupyter Notebookを突っ込んで実行してます。
OSはWSL on Ubuntuです。

### VSCode

バージョン: 1.78.2 (user setup)
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0

### Python

Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41)
[GCC 9.4.0]

### Jupyter

2020/11/12 4:14:18
前回のリリース日
2023/5/19 18:27:22
最終更新
2023/5/5 11:35:36
識別子
ms-toolsai.jupyter

### ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS \n \l

### WSL

WSL バージョン: 1.2.5.0
カーネル バージョン: 5.15.90.1
WSLg バージョン: 1.0.51
MSRDC バージョン: 1.2.3770
Direct3D バージョン: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore バージョン: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows バージョン: 10.0.22621.1702

### python modules

```
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
asttokens              2.2.1
attrs                  19.3.0
Automat                0.8.0
backcall               0.2.0
blinker                1.4
certifi                2019.11.28
chardet                3.0.4
charset-normalizer     3.1.0
Click                  7.0
cloud-init             23.1.2
colorama               0.4.3
comm                   0.1.3
command-not-found      0.3
configobj              5.0.6
constantly             15.1.0
contourpy              1.0.7
cryptography           2.8
cycler                 0.11.0
dbus-python            1.2.16
debugpy                1.6.7
decorator              5.1.1
distro                 1.4.0
distro-info            0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints            0.3
executing              1.2.0
fonttools              4.39.4
htmlmin                0.1.12
httplib2               0.14.0
hyperlink              19.0.0
idna                   2.8
ImageHash              4.3.1
importlib-metadata     6.6.0
importlib-resources    5.12.0
incremental            16.10.1
ipykernel              6.23.1
ipython                8.12.2
japanize-matplotlib    1.1.3
jedi                   0.18.2
Jinja2                 3.1.2
joblib                 1.2.0
jsonpatch              1.22
jsonpointer            2.0
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter_client         8.2.0
jupyter_core           5.3.0
keyring                18.0.1
kiwisolver             1.4.4
language-selector      0.1
launchpadlib           1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient     0.14.2
lazr.uri               1.0.3
MarkupSafe             2.1.2
matplotlib             3.6.3
matplotlib-inline      0.1.6
more-itertools         4.2.0
multimethod            1.9.1
nest-asyncio           1.5.6
netifaces              0.10.4
networkx               3.1
numpy                  1.23.5
oauthlib               3.1.0
packaging              23.1
pandas                 1.5.3
pandas-profiling       3.6.6
parso                  0.8.3
patsy                  0.5.3
pexpect                4.6.0
phik                   0.12.3
pickleshare            0.7.5
Pillow                 9.5.0
pip                    23.1.2
platformdirs           3.5.1
prompt-toolkit         3.0.38
psutil                 5.9.5
pure-eval              0.2.2
pyasn1                 0.4.2
pyasn1-modules         0.2.1
pydantic               1.10.7
Pygments               2.15.1
PyGObject              3.36.0
PyHamcrest             1.9.0
PyJWT                  1.7.1
pymacaroons            0.13.0
PyNaCl                 1.3.0
pyOpenSSL              19.0.0
pyparsing              3.0.9
pyrsistent             0.15.5
pyserial               3.4
python-apt             2.0.1+ubuntu0.20.4.1
python-dateutil        2.8.2
python-debian          0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz                   2023.3
PyWavelets             1.4.1
PyYAML                 5.3.1
pyzmq                  25.0.2
requests               2.28.2
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0
scikit-learn           1.2.2
scipy                  1.9.3
seaborn                0.12.2
SecretStorage          2.3.1
service-identity       18.1.0
setuptools             45.2.0
simplejson             3.16.0
six                    1.14.0
sos                    4.4
ssh-import-id          5.10
stack-data             0.6.2
statsmodels            0.13.5
systemd-python         234
tangled-up-in-unicode  0.2.0
threadpoolctl          3.1.0
tornado                6.3.2
tqdm                   4.64.1
traitlets              5.9.0
Twisted                18.9.0
typeguard              2.13.3
typing_extensions      4.5.0
tzdata                 2023.3
ubuntu-advantage-tools 8001
ufw                    0.36
unattended-upgrades    0.1
urllib3                1.25.8
visions                0.7.5
wadllib                1.3.3
wcwidth                0.2.6
wheel                  0.40.0
ydata-profiling        4.1.2
zipp                   3.15.0
zope.interface         4.7.1
```

## 5/22追記

ご指摘の通りipywidgetsを導入してみたのですが、また別のエラーが出ました。
[image: エラー]

### 5/22追追記

kunifさんのご指示の通り、パッケージの更新を行ったところエラーが消えました！
しかし、依然としてpylanceのエラーは出続けています…
実行する分には問題ないですがさすがに放置というには…

Comment: 「エラー。ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipywidgets'」はどこで発生したのでしょうか？エラー詳細を質問に追記していただきたいです。

Comment: VSCodeのJupyter拡張機能ではなく、Jupyter notebookで試した場合でも同様のエラーとなりますか？

Comment: ちなみに`Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) [GCC 9.4.0]`とかエラーメッセージで表示されるパスが`~/.local/lib`で始まっているということは、Linux系かmacOSということでしょうか？ その辺の情報・版数やPythonにインストールされているモジュール一覧とかも追記した方が良いのでは？

Comment: ubuntu on wslのCUIをlocal環境のGoogleDrive上で動かしています。

Comment: 提示された`python modules`には、質問のエラーメッセージにあるように`ipywidgets`が入っていませんので、それが原因なのでは？ google colabでモジュールのリストを取得すると、そちらには`ipywidgets`は入っています。不足しているならWSLの環境には自分で追加すれば良いでしょう。

Comment: もしかしたらモジュール間の版数の整合性が崩れているとかでは？ google colabでは動作した訳ですから、それに入っている各モジュールの版数に合わせてみるのはどうでしょう？ あるいは、[pip-review](https://pypi.org/project/pip-review/) で`--auto`オプションを使うと1回で全てのモジュールが最新になるよう処理してくれるので簡単です。あと[pandas-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/)は[ydata-profiling](https://pypi.org/project/ydata-profiling/)に変わるそうなので、そちらで試してみるのはどうでしょう？

Comment: この辺の記事 [Pylance が pd.read_csv() の戻り値を DataFrame として認識してくれない](https://qiita.com/shiba54/items/5df469b208b2ae9e2028), [Pylance can not find parameters in sklearn classes #1139](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1139), [pylance-release/CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) を見ると、使っている pylance の版数が古いか、sklearn対応は複数の版数にまたがって行われているようなので最新版でもまだ対応していないか、あるいは何かオプション等を設定する必要があるのか、といったことが考えられます。

Comment: 細かい話ですが「エラーは出るけど実行できる」という書き方は「実行できているなら問題ないのでは？」といった印象を与えます。何が問題なのかが伝わるようなタイトル・本文を心がけてみてください。